# How to apply readonly to group of textboxes in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to make readonly to these textboxes in javascript. Readonly property apply to several textboxes by single javascript. how to make this.

```
 <div class="box-body" id="readonly_owner">
           <label for="owner_deviceid">Owner Device Id</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control readonly_owner" id="owner_deviceid">
           <label for="owner_name">Owner Name</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control readonly_owner" id="owner_name">
    </div>
```

I have using javascript like this or there is an option for apply this property to class. Iam using getElementsByClassName()  but it doesn't work

```
document.getElementById('readonly_owner').readOnly ="readonly";
```

How to apply readonly property to group of textboxes and also remove readonly property

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery, you can do this in a single line:

```
$('.readonly_owner').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
```

Or without jQuery:

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('readonly_owner');
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i += 1) {
    items[i].readOnly = true;
}
```